# Best practices on how to stream data to server .NET

Tags: .net, http, streaming

Say I want to have a server that can accept 2GB file over network, HTTP. And the data is easily readable with well known format, think something like CSV.

Is there a way to gradually process the data the user has uploaded into file upload "INPUT = FILE" control while the data is still uploading through 32kbps modem?

I'm reading HttpRequest Stream, and other streaming documentation, but haven't found a confirmation if IIS, ASP.NET even allows it and if I'm just not wasting my time.

And, from development perspective, is it possible to simulate slow stream?

Comment: 2GB file over 32kbps modem? Assuming symetrical upload (which it probably isn't), you're looking at (in the best case) an 18h+ upload. You'd better hope that the connection is bullet proof, or it's going to be a highly frustrating experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WCF Streamin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)g that you can use `netTcpBinding` or `basicHttpBinding`. I have used it and It is super fast and efficient - really impressive.

And yes you can simulate slow transfer, you just need to write to your stream slowly (pauses in the middle).

Comment: Ok, started to read the document. But just a quick question, can you use the basicHttp/TcpBinding in an ASPX page? Seems that the request is already packed for me. Or do I have to make an Ajax request that interacts with webservice (asmx) like target?

Comment: Not on ASPX page. You can host WCF on IIS and then have a client to stream. It has to be a client capable of such as SL, WPF or Console.

Comment: So if I want to upstream data through html file input control, I can just give up?

Comment: Yeah... give it up mate :) There are so many hurdles. IIS only allows 8 MB upload... and even if you up it, then browser could just stop halfway.